# Copy a file and replace multiple keywords using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I need to read TestQuery and HiveOpFile from below excel sheet for **each testId** at run time and need to replace them in a python script (which i copied from another file.). I tried following code:

[image]

e.g. For TestID XXX-123

```py
#have working code to read both columns data as per TestID.
HiveTestQL =  'Select UNIT, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(EFFECTIVE_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss")) from Table1;' 
TargetFile =  'Z:/home/user/Result1.csv'
```

.

```py
#file code which i am copying  HiveBeelineConn.py

import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


connection_url = "jdbc:hive2://axxxx.com:10000/xxxxxxxxprincipal=hive/_HOST@BDS.xxxxx.COM"
############To Update Query from excel################
sql = sql_q             
 
cmd1 = 'INSERT OVERWRITE  DIRECTORY "'+ exportDir + '/" ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "'+ delimetedBy + '" ESCAPED BY \"\\\\\ " ' + nld + sql +";"
val = subprocess.check_output(hive_query, shell=True)

############To Update file name from excel################
opFile = hiveOpFile
```

Code I tried to copy file and replace string

```py
with open('Z:\HiveBeelineConnToRun.py', 'wb+') as output, open('Z:\HiveBeelineConn.py', 'rb') as input:
    copyfileobj(input, output)
    output.close()

with open('Z:\HiveBeelineConnToRun.py', 'r') as output1:
    f_data = output1.read()
f_data = f_data.replace('sql_q', f"'{HiveTestQL}'" ).replace('hiveOpFile', f"'{TargetFile}'" )

with open('Z:\HiveBeelineConnToRun.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write(f_data)
    file.close()
```

Above code work fine and create a python file HiveBeelineConnToRun.py copying from HiveBeelineConn.py and replace the values. Here I am using 3 with statement to replace just 2 string in one file. Is there any more efficient way to do it? I tried using For loop but it is resulting null file.

```py
with open('Z:\HiveBeelineConnToRun4.py', 'r+') as output1:
    f_data = output1.read()

    for line in f_data:
        new_line = line.replace('sql_q', HiveTestQL)
        new_line = line.replace('hiveOpFile', TargetFile)
        output1.write(new_line)
    output1.close()
```

Comment: Why not use a pandas `DataFrame`?

Comment: @bigbounty
Can you please guide with sample code or refer to some sites ?